# JSON Record Count return 0 ? EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.define('GoogleMarkerModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['ID','Locating','MainPower','Acc','PowerOff','Alarm','Speed','Direction','Latitude','Longitude','DateTime','MainID','IOState','OilState']
    });

    var MarkerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'GoogleMarkerModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-googlemarker.php',
            baseParams: {  //here you can define params you want to be sent on each request from this store
                        mainid: 'value1'
                        },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
            }

        }
    });

MarkerStore.load({
params: {  
        mainid: 1,
        }
})
```

this is the record return in firebug and i m trying to count record  with `alert(MarkerStore.getCount());` return 0 ? why?
i have double check the fields name,all are correct. what wrong is this?

```
[{"ID":"1808","Locating":"1","MainPower":"0","Acc":"1","PowerOff":"1","Alarm":"128","Speed":"0","Direction":"293","Latitude":"5.391788482666016","Longitude":"100.29693603515625","DateTime":"2013-02-19 15:44:36","MainID":"1","IOState":"0","OilState":"0"}]
```

### UPDATE

```
Ext.define('GoogleMarkerModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty:'MainID',
    fields: ['ID','Locating','MainPower','Acc','PowerOff','Alarm','Speed','Direction','Latitude','Longitude','DateTime','MainID','IOState','OilState']
});

var MarkerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    model: 'GoogleMarkerModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'get-googlemarker.php',
        baseParams: {  //here you can define params you want to be sent on each request from this store
                    mainid: 'value1'
                    },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            idProperty : 'MainID',
        }

    }
});
```

i have added idproperty,but still can't work

Comment: When are you asking for the count? Because the ajax call is asynchronous, you might be querying for the value before the store has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you use idProperty?

A look at the [api-docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader) gives you a short example. Your proxy reader should look similar and your json even so. Use root property.